# generate RSA public key having public modulus and exponent

Tags: rsa, public-key, openssl

i want to generate an RSA public public key file using openssl (or other tools) having public modulus and exponent, so i can use it later to encrypt files

i have this:

```
the modulus: 

"BEB90F8AF5D8A7C7DA8CA74AC43E1EE8A48E6860C0D46A5D690BEA082E3A74E1"
+"571F2C58E94EE339862A49A811A31BB4A48F41B3BCDFD054C3443BB610B5418B"
+"3CBAFAE7936E1BE2AFD2E0DF865A6E59C2B8DF1E8D5702567D0A9650CB07A43D"
+"E39020969DF0997FCA587D9A8AE4627CF18477EC06765DF3AA8FB459DD4C9AF3"

the exponent: 0x10001
```

so how can i generate the public key from those, so i can use it to encrypt some data, or maybe there's a way to use these directly for encryption ?

Comment: That is great you want to do that! What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: i couldn't find anything, apparently i can do the inverse; getting the modulus and exponent form a public key

Comment: What format is everything in right now?

Comment: When I need to do the same, I use a python module. Here you'll find the doc: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#construct 
You just need two integers (modulus and public exponent), then you export it with the RSA.export('PEM') function. (Give a look to the examples)

Comment: thx that would help

Comment: Downvoted, it's not even clear what format the output needs adhere to. If I'd be really evil I would say you already have a public keyas you have the modulus and public exponent.

Comment: i edited my question, and added some info

Comment: The public key *is* the modulus and exponent. The tool you want to use probably needs a format that isn't the one you present in the question. But your question gives no clue as to what format you want. It's also not clear what you want to do in the first place. Encrypting files is pointless if you can't decrypt them. Who has the private key and what format can they decrypt? This determines what format you would encrypt in. Then, asymmetric cryptography isn't used to encrypt files, only to encrypt very small messages such as a single-use symmetric key used only to encrypt one file.

Comment: @Gilles i want to encrypt some words not files. and about the format "-----BEGIN OF PUBLIC KEY-----" and the key after it

Comment: If this is just about openssl - the command line, please ask at superuser or another Q/A site about tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got this, it's not with openssl, but python

```
e = 0x10001
N = 0x1234214....

words = open("words.txt").read().split()

for w in words:
     ww = int(w.encode("hex"), 16)
     print pow(ww, e, N)
```